# Is there a way to make an online customer tax exempt?

Tags: drupal-6, ubercart

In Ubercart, Is there a way to make an online customer tax exempt and if so, how? I have tried creating a role called 'tax_exempt' and editing the conditions so that this role does not apply to the tax (admin/store/ca/uc_taxes_1/edit/conditions), but when I go to the checkout page, it is still calculated taxes for this user (I have added them to the tax_exempt role)

Here is the condition setup:

```
Operator: AND
Condition: Check an order's billing State/Province

   State/Province: New York

Condition: Check the role of the user.

   Negate this condition = true
   Operator: OR     
   Roles: tax_exempt, wholesale
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to go into admin/store/ca/ and enable the tax trigger for it to work